# When trying to add routes in react,the webpage stays blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am a begginer in react and I was creating a webapp with multiple sites, so I downloaded react-router-dom with the npm command, however when I try using it, the webpages shows nothing.

Code:

```
import '../App.css';
import Header from "./header"
import Custom from "./custom"
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter,Routes as Switch ,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
let globalID =0

function App() {

  return <div>
    <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <p>Best to do list</p>
      <Switch>
      <Route path = "/hello-world">
        <h1>I am on route hello world</h1>
      </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    <h2>I dont change with the page</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
}

export default App;
```

Website:
[image: Website failing]

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console? Is your `App` component actually mounted? Does it work if you remove the routes?

Answer (score 0):

**Routes** only accept  a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>` as children

**change  :**

```
<Route path = "/hello-world">
        <h1>I am on route hello world</h1>
      </Route>
```

**to:**

```
<Route path = "/hello-world" element={<h1> I am on route hello world</h1>}>
        
      </Route>
```